# How to properly use "this" within nested .each()(s)? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my nested usage of `.each`:

```
itemData["segmentos"] = {};
$("[id^='item-segmentos-']").each(function() {
    $("[id^='item-tipo-']").each(function() {
        itemData["segmentos"][$(outerthis).val()] = $(innerthis).val();
    });
});
```

How can I use the "outerthis" within the scope of the inner .each?

Comment: There's an `each`-specific answer which is not covered in the referenced duplicate (and which I think is a better solution for this specific question, as per my answer), hence my vote to reopen as not-an-exact-duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the 'outer' `this` in the inner `each()` loops, you simply have to cache the 'outer' `this` in a variable, and then refer to that variable in place of using `this` within the inner `each()` loops:

```
itemData["segmentos"] = {};
$("[id^='item-segmentos-']").each(function() {
    var outerThis = $(this);
    $("[id^='item-tipo-']").each(function() {
        var innerThis = $(this);
        itemData["segmentos"][outerThis.val()] = innerThis.val();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can assign it to a variable in the outer function. This will form a closure and the inner function will have access to the outer variable:

```
itemData["segmentos"] = {};
$("[id^='item-segmentos-']").each(function() {
    var outerthis = this;
    $("[id^='item-tipo-']").each(function() {
        itemData["segmentos"][$(outerthis).val()] = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

But note that jQuery passes the index and element as parameters to your callback, which can make for clearer code, e.g.

```
itemData["segmentos"] = {};
$("[id^='item-segmentos-']").each(function(oIndex, outerElement) {
    $("[id^='item-tipo-']").each(function(iIndex, innerElement) {
        itemData["segmentos"][$(outerElement).val()] = $(innerElement).val();
    });
});
```

Comment: Just pointing out the obvious. In your first example, `innerthis` is not defined.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks, fixed